# Django STMP with IONOS

Tags: django, smtp, ionos

Having an adress mail managed by IONOS, I'm struggling to set it up with Django to be able to send mails automatically.

Here's my error:

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I personnalized the SMTP in my settings:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL="mymail"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.ionos.fr'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusername' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mymdp'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

and here's how I send mails:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
def send_forgotten_password_mail(self, request, pk=None):
    send_mail(
        'Subject here',
        'Here is the message.',
        None,
        ['tosend'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

I'm not that used to send mails through SMTP with Django, so I might miss something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.ionos.de'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusername' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypw'
```

Comment: It does work thank you. I kept the same EMAIL_HOST and changed the EMAIL_USE_TLS and the EMAIL_PORT to match yours.